# How can I stop my laptop waking from suspend as the lid is closed?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, power-management, kde

I have an Alienware M17x with Kubuntu 14.10. When I suspend to RAM and close the lid, very often it will wake up after a few seconds of sleep. Sometimes not. I get the feeling it's related to how quickly the lid is closed, but I have no hard data on this.

[Here is my dmesg](http://pastebin.com/vN3VTd1x). There was a suspend-wake incident a few minutes ago.

**EDIT:** `dmesg | grep -i lid` shows nice, clean "lid opened" and "lid closed" events -- this is not a bounce issue.

Comment: Assuming your power settings are set correctly, perhaps there is a loose connection? There are just buttons on the lid that detect if it is closed or not so perhaps they are getting bumped or something.

Comment: Looks like a [bouncing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Switch#Contact_bounce) issue on the lid switch, where the switch makes contact several times - the first one does put the system to sleep as expected but then a second pulse wakes it up again.

Comment: It sometimes happens ten seconds or so after the lid has closed. This makes me want to rule out bouncing.

Comment: Also, sometimes the lid is already fully down *before* the shutdown has happened. And even if it is a case of bounce, the question is then "how do I make my sleep/resume process bounce-tolerant?"

Comment: Do you have some RJ45 jack connected to LAN? Maybe it is some sort of Wake on LAN event. I have sometimes used the "Wake on LAN Traffic" mode for ethernet cards. It is not very usual to configure like this, but for network traffic capturing it is worth the price.

Comment: Nothing is plugged in except the power cable.

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem on both Windows and Linux. It is caused by my mediaplayer (mediaplayer-classic on Windows and mplayer on Linux), whenever I close my mediaplayer and put it in "sleep" it stays asleep until I wake it up.

However, this is not a fix but a workaround.

**UPDATE**
Yes, this is supposed to be a comment. But as a new member I am not able to place comments yet, but I can place answers... (It should be the other way around if you ask me)
Since this is how I "fixed" it, I chose to post it anyways.

Comment: This appears to be primarily a comment.